# Saving a python dictionary in hdf5 where values corresponding to each key is another dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, hdf5, h5py

I have a python dictionary like this

```
`my_dict = {'name_1' : {'value1' : a float32 numpy array, 
                        'value2' : a float32 numpy array}
           {'name_2' : {'value1' : a float32 numpy array, 
                        'value2' : a float32 numpy array}}`
```

How can I save it in `hdf5` using `h5py` so that I can later on access the key-value pairs as they are represented now in the python dictionary?

Comment: What have you tried so far? From your data, you can create two groups and append the data in each one.

Comment: @Nain please add the code as [mcve]

Comment: @Nain you can create groups from a group. So this will consist in another loop or `dset3 = f.create_dataset('subgroup2/dataset_three', (10,), dtype='i')ˋ

Comment: Like Y0da said a bit more information would be good. What's the expected size of the float32 arrays and are the arrays of the same shape? Is performance very important?

Comment: Use `groups`.  The lowest level keys will be `dataset` names,  Dataset values are arrays.

Comment: Relevant [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120802/recursively-save-python-dictionaries-to-hdf5-files-using-h5py)